# Hijack audio with Java?

Tags: java, audio, audio-recording

I have been trying to modify some code found [at the bottom of this page](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.sound/capturing-audio-with-java-sound-api.html) in order to hijack system audio with Java. Here's the part that I modified in captureAudio():

```
Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[0]); // "Java Sound Audio Engine"
final TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(info);
```

Now when I run this code, it throws this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: interface TargetDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
```

I have tried changing my format to fit with the required format, but the exception doesn't go and nothing is recorded. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot "hijack" system audio in java, a la Audio Hijack Pro.

Comment: Because Java is executed in a virtual machine?

Comment: Sort of. It would be more correct to say something like "the java platform doesn't support that feature."

Answer (score 2):

Try out the following

```
TargetDataLine line;
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, 
    format); // format is an AudioFormat object
if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
    // Handle the error.
    }
    // Obtain and open the line.
try {
    line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    line.open(format);
} catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        // Handle the error.
    //... 
}
```

It is taken from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html

To create an AudioFormat , use

> new AudioFormat(float sampleRate, int sampleSizeInBits, int channels, boolean signed, boolean bigEndian);
>   sampleRate = 44100f;
>   sampleSizeInBits = 16;
>   channels = 2;
>   signed = true;
>   bigEndian = true/false which ever works

Mostly the above configuration works on most platforms including Linux and windows, have not tried Mac as of now